# Pre select an "unknown" option in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I'm trying to pre select an option in a select dropdown, I know how to do it if the value for the options are static. But what if they change dynamically? In my case I got a list of albums which updates a lot so I never know what the value of the options will be. I tried selecting the first album in the list by using `ng-init` like this:

```
<select class="rounded bold" ng-model="selectedAlbum" ng-init="selectedAlbum='album[0].albumName'">
    <option ng-repeat="album in albumsList" value="{{album.albumName}}" ng-bind="album.albumName">
</select>
```

But with no luck, from my searches I can't really find anything that answers this. It might be `ng-options` but from what I've seen that doesn't generate options with a binding on them. Like I've done in the code above.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Use `ng-options` and then set the `model`

Comment: just to you to be aware. in your ng-init directive you are referencing the wrong variable. It must be albumList[0] instead

Comment: @tymeJV Any idea why this: ng-options="opt as opt.albumName for album in albumList", isn't working?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, because you're using `opt` and `album` interchangeably.  You want either `opt as opt.albumName for opt in albumList`, or `album as album.albumName for album in albumList`; however, that's the same as not even including `opt as...` since you're just setting it to the full object.  You'd use that if you wanted, for example, `opt.id as opt.albumName for opt in albumList`

Comment: @Tom Well it doesn't work with either unfortunately.. It must be "album asalbum.albumName" since I use "album.albumName" as the binding in my original code, right?

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle, or jsBin?  In my example [here](http://jsbin.com/rokekuhito/1/edit), it seems to work fine

Comment: @Tom I'm using the exact same code as you but mine ain't working.. I'll see if I can get a Bin working tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ng-options` directive to build you list, and include an option with an empty value:

```
<select class="rounded bold"
        ng-model="selectedAlbum" 
        ng-options="album.albumName for album in albumsList">
  <option value="">-- choose album--</option>
</select>
```

See [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/rokekuhito/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller just change the selectedAlbum model to the value you want

```
$scope.selectedAlbum = albumsList[0].albumName
```

Answer (score 0):

If `albumsList` changes, the model (`selectedAlbum`) may not match any `albumName`. In this case, `selectedAlbum` will remain on its previous value, and  angular adds an "unknown" `option` to your `select`. As I understood your question,in this situation, you want the first item in the new `albumList` to be selected (which BTW I think is a reasonable action).
In order to achieve this, you can watch `albumList` and check if `selectedAlbum` is valid according to new `albumList`. If not, you can change it to first item:

```
$scope.$watch("alubmList", function(newAlbumList){
    if(angular.isArray(newAlbumList) && newAlbumList.length){
        var albumNames = newAlbumList.map(function(album){
            return album.name;
        });
        if(albumNames.indexOf($scope.selectedAlbum)<0)
            scope.selectedAlbum = newAlbumList[0].name;
    }
});
```

**side note:**
you can rewrite your html with ng-options:

```
<select class="rounded bold" ng-options="album.albumName for album in albumsList"></select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply u can make this with old JavaScript :

```
var elementid=document.getElementById("elementid");
var unknown_option=elementid.options[1].value;
elementid.value=unknown_option;
```

//options[1] selects the first option, if 2 then the 2nd.. etc
but of course if u want the last option u will have to make length function then loop or directly "inverted index" :)